How to resolve this IBM DB2 Community Installation issue?
I am facing this issue where I am trying to install IBM DB2 Community.
This error message pops up in the end of the installation which rollbacks the entire installation.
I tried to do repair operations on Microsoft Visual C++ applications, but doesn't seem to work.
If anybody has faced this issue in past and got it resolved, please help out over here.

Issue in the log file

Google Drive File Path Link For The Log
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MP2UldAC75bpmP47tNk8uVSbq8_XRuxo/view?usp=sharing
System Specifications
System Type : 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Processor : AMD Ryzen 3 2200G with Radeon Vega Graphics 3.50 GHz
RAM : 8.00 GB
Windows Version : Version 21H2 (OS Build 22000.2538)
Admin Rights : Administrator

alors you juste installing the binary or did you choose to create a new database, can you upload the log file

@mshabou There is no option to upload the log file when posting questions on Stack overflow + the log file is very big to post screenshot. Any specific area where you want me to take screenshot of the log?

please poste the portion of the log where you see the error

This is not a programming question, but rather installation/configuration. As your symptom is most likely specific to your workstation configuration, we cannot help unless you precisely detail exactly your configuration of operating-system, admin-rights, windows-version-and-edition details etc. Normally all this information is in the log file, you can upload the logfile to a pastebin or publicly accessible cloud location and give a link to the log file.

@mshabou I have updated my question. Let me know if more details are required from my end.

@mao I have posted the log, system details as well as the image where the error is exactly in the log. Let me know if more details are required.

what is the version of DB2 are you installing ?

Windows server 2022 is only compatible with db2 11.5.8  and higher

This is not quite a full answer, but it cannot fit into a comment. IMHO this looks like an IBM defect.
The immediate cause is that just before completing the installation,  the installation-program (which appears to be for Db2 v11.5.9.0) runs the command "C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\regsvr32 /s C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\function\db2olefn.dll" (to register OLE) which fails with error code 3. This causes the entire installation to get rolled back, which is what your log file shows.  It seems absurd to do a full rollback at this point(instead of reporting the error, and allowing manual recovery).
IBM documented this symptom previously in different scenarios, see https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/registration-ole-regsvr32-command-db2olefndll-fails-when-silently-installing-db2-without-creating-instance
There was also a previous bug number IY9806 for a similar symptom on older versions , perhaps the root cause was elusive if the symptom is returning in 2024.
Apparently IBM did not see that the same symptom will cause a non-silent installation to fully rollback in specific circumstances (such as yours). IBM did not document an underlying root cause however (i.e. why the error code 3 gets returned), so it is unclear if IBM knows the root cause. A commmon reason for regsvr32 to fail with error code 3 is that MS-Windows got an error from its LoadLibrary routine when attempting to load db2oldfn.dll, but since IBM foolishly chose to use the '/s' option to regsvr32, which disables error messages from regsvr32, we cannot know from the log file the real cause of failure. Another cause of failure can be NTFS permissions, your question does not state whether or not your machine is attached to a Microsoft Domain , or whether the account performing the installation has administrative rights etc. All these details matter.
One option is to wait for IBM to fix it, assuming someone reports the defect to IBM via a formal support contract. This relies on someone reporting it to IBM , supplying the detailed log files (IBM might ask for a tracefile in addition to the logfile), and for IBM to be able to recreate it, and for IBM to be able to fix it (or get a fix from Microsoft if the root cause is some issue inside MS-Windows).
Another option is to experiment with the installation options and administrative rights to see if you can get the installer to NOT try to register the OLE (or at least to not rollback), and then do that OLE registration manually after installation.  Ideally there would be a way to specify (perhaps via response file, or command-line options) to either not register specific components or to log and continue if their registration fails.
Additinally, if you have the skills to debug and dig under the covers, you might trace the behaviour of MS-Windows while the installation-program is attempting to run the registration of OLE for Db2. Use the Microsoft process monitor (procmon64.exe) and filter for events relating to process name regsvr32 (there may be many, allow time for this).  In addition, for the previous failed installation there may be some details of interest if you search in the Microsoft Event Viewer for evidence of failure cause.
